# SQL Server Management Studio - Failed to start debugger (Error 229)

Tags: sql-server, debugging, management-studio-express

I put a breakpoint somewhere in a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and then press start debugger. I end up getting

> Error 229 error (failed to start debugger)

It appears to be a problem with permission, and I tried to ask the DB admin to execute

```
grant execute on sp_enable_sql_debug to my_login_name
```

command, but the syntax of the command is erroneous. Any ideas ?

Comment: I read somewhere, the minimum security requirement for debugging is sysadmin (Windows Server Role, not db). Try that.

Answer (score 3):

Simple thing to over come this error. Go for sql server db and  select **security** and click on **login**. In that u can see your **login** **name** . Right click on it and click **properties** . In the left screen u can see the **role** in that u want **check** **public** and **sysadmin** . Now restart your db and visual studio. Now it work fine and i have clearly explained